# VB.Net ConnectionString with a local .mdf database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

I am publishing a project application and I think having a connectionstring with this format

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\iaprubillos\My Documents\PROJECT\myProject\database\myDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
```

is not a friendly and definitely won't work when I will run the application on other computers. Question: Can I use a connectionstring in a format of

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\myDatabase.mdf"
```

and store the database in bin folder so that when I Build my project and compile to an .exe file, the .exe file can still access the database?

Comment: Why dont you just add the mdf and ldf files into sql server directly. That way it become part of sql server instance and you do not have to attach the file.

Comment: @vasin1987 I am planning not to install sql server when I "install" the application on other computer. It's like a stand-alone program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` to get the path where your application is running from. So you can modify your connextion string code like this:

```
cn.ConnectionString = String.format("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0}\myDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath)
```